# Which Cow should be donated to brahmana? Cow with calf or Any single healthy Cow?

Tags: krishna, cows, daana

Namaste, If someone wishes to buy a cow and donate to a Brahmana, Is it necessary that at present that cow should be in the milking stage or is it okay to donate a healthy cow which will get pregnant after donation?

Kindly guide me with more related details.